# Streamprovider i am getting this issue "The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building ConsumerStreamData

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, inherited-widget

[image: error popup on terminal window]

main.dart file contain all the providers

```
  return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context)=>AppData()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context)=> UtilData()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context)=> ButtonData()),
            StreamProvider(create: (context)=> streamProvider.getScanningData(),
                initialData: false),
          ],
```

so in another statefulwidget class in appbar im trying to get that stream value using consumer widget and i am getting this ,

```
appBar: AppBar(
leading: Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 1.5,
),
child: InkWell(
onTap: (){
print('presed');
_scaffoldKey1.currentState?.openDrawer();
},
child: Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.grey[100], // border color
shape: BoxShape.circle,
),
actions: [
   Consumer<StreamData>(
   builder: (_,value,__){
    if(value == true )
    return Text('true');
    else
   return Text('false');
     },
    ),
  ],
 ),
```

this is my stream class that gets bluetooth data

```
class StreamData{

   Stream<bool> getScanningData(){
    return FlutterBluePlus.instance.isScanning;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In consumer widget you code should be

```
 Consumer<bool>(
   builder: (_,value,__){
    if(value)
    return Text('true');
    else
   return Text('false');
     },
    ),
```

Comment: how consumer identify the data without mentioning the StreamData class?

Comment: StreamProvider(create: (context)=> streamProvider.getScanningData(),
                initialData: false),
 streamProvider.getScanningData() returns bool, therefore You are creating a streamprovider of boolean value instead of a StreamData, so u need to consume a boolean value

Comment: ok fine , if i am using one more streamprovider in multiproviders  with bool type is this work?

Comment: If u want to use one or more boolean streamprovider, then it wont allow you, instead either create a changenotifier provider or instead of providing a boolean, provide a class